# Download a server-generated KML file with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, download, kml

I want to create an API that generates a KML file compatible with Google Earth/Maps API for downloading.

Currently I'm facing a 406 Not Acceptable error.

The code is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/kml",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<InputStream> kml() throws IOException
{
    InputStream is = geocodingManager.generateKml(geocodingProviderId);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Samo.kml");
    headers.add("content-type", "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");

    return new HttpEntity<InputStream>(is, headers);

}
```

If I invoke the API (`http://localhost/context/path-to/kml`) with browser or RESTClient plugin (even by setting explicitly the `Accept: *.*` or `Accept: */*` headers) I always get error `406 Not Acceptable`.

I had first tried to set the `produces` attribute to the annotation, then decided to remove it as an attempt, but that didn't fix.

How can I download a KML to my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/kml")
public void kml(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    InputStream is = request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/1.0_week_age.kml");;
    IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/kml")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> kml(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
{   //get your input stream here 
    InputStream is = request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/1.0_week_age.kml");
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(is), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

or even this will work due to default ByteArrayMessageConverter

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/kml")
public @ResponseBody byte[] kml(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    InputStream is = request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/1.0_week_age.kml");
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
}
```

If are accessing some rest service and then returning the kml you may also consider using [RestTemplate](http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate)

Comment: All of them works for me, may be some configuration missing for you.